# How to make the gif photo to be same width as the table?

Tags: html, css

I want to make the gif  photo to be same width(6 inches)as the table with following css code.

```css
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td {
      border: 1px solid red;
      width: 2in;
    }
    div {
      text-indent: 2em;
      background: url(title_bg.gif) left;
      width: 6in;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<header>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</header>

<body>
  <br />
  <br />

  <div>result</div>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        experiment project
      </td>
      <td>
        unit
      </td>
      <td>
        value
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        experiment project1
      </td>
      <td>
        unit
      </td>
      <td>
        value
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        experiment project2
      </td>
      <td>
        unit
      </td>
      <td>
        value
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

The title_bg.gif is 
[image]

The output is as the following:

[image]

I have set the image to be 6 in ,and three tds here ,3*2=6.
Why the table is larger than the image?
How to make them equal width?

Comment: Almost impossible to answer without seeing all CSS - can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because of `1px` border and default `padding` which is `1px` if you remove  the border and make padding `0` then the result is-

```css
table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td {
/*border:1px solid red;*/
    background:#ccc;
    width:2in;
    padding:0;
}
div {
    text-indent:2em;
    background: url('https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRn211PPwWEdhmVO4YK4y5ITrIvOUW3bWKHRMsbCZYRLdbkoYPj') left ;
    width:6in;
}
```

```html
<div> result   </div>

<table>
<tr>
  <td>
  experiment project
  </td>
  <td>
  unit
  </td>
  <td>
  value
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
  experiment project1
  </td>
  <td>
  unit
  </td>
  <td>
  value
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
  experiment project2
  </td>
  <td>
  unit
  </td>
  <td>
  value
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[Calc()](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/) can be useful for you in this condition.

```
table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td {
    border:1px solid red;
    background:gray;
    width:2in;
    padding:0;

}
div {
    text-indent:2em;
    background:url(yourimagepath.gif)left ;
    width:calc(6in + 4px);
}
```

*Note: - see the browser support for calc().*

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour of most browsers is to exclude an element's border-width from the calculation of its width. This means your td's total width (width + border) will be 2in + 2 * 1px. To fix this you can set `box-sizing: border-box;`
More info here : https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 1):

just give the table the same width of div

```
table{
 width:6in;
}
```